# How could I implement the equivalent of NextPrime

Tags: programming, implementation-details, number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to know what an implementation of the function `NextPrime` would look like if it were implemented in *Mathematica*'s core language.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Robert. What have you tried? It is preferable if you show some effort in working out your problem for yourself, and give some indication of where you got stuck. Please see the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details.

Comment: Are you looking for any one way to implement it or do you want to know how it is actually implemented?

Comment: What Szabolcs means to say is... `NextPrime` IS actually implemented in Mathematica. Try `Trace[NextPrime[6]]`. The core of it is quite similar to what I posted

Answer (score 9):

```
(nextPrime[#1] = #2) & @@@ {{-3, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 2}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}};
nextPrime[n_Integer?EvenQ] := nextPrime[n - 1];
nextPrime[n_Integer] /; PrimeQ[n + 2] := n + 2;
nextPrime[n_Integer] := nextPrime[n + 2]
nextPrime[n_ /; n \[Element] Reals] := nextPrime[Floor@n]
```

Comment: There are only a few prime even integers. Perhaps you could take some advantage

Comment: There you go @belisarius

Comment: Ok. You got the NextPrime yellow belt +1

Comment: @belisarius a *few*?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, my first English teacher was proud of me. He was deaf.

Comment: @Artes, better?

Comment: @Rojo Now better +1

Answer (score 5):

Just a joke:

```
nextp[i_] := Prime[PrimePi[i] + 1]
```

Comment: `somewhatNextPrime[x_] :=  FindInstance[\[FormalN] > x, \[FormalN], Primes]`

Answer (score 5):

For reference, here is the v7 code behind `NextPrime`, which is hard to read before stripping all the private context names.

```
NextPrime[1]; (* preload the definition *)
Unprotect[NextPrime];
ClearAttributes[NextPrime, ReadProtected];
$Context = "NumberTheory`NextPrimeDump`";
FullDefinition[NextPrime]
```

Yields:

```
Attributes[NextPrime] = {Listable}

NextPrime[-3] := -2

NextPrime[-2] := 2

NextPrime[-1] := 2

NextPrime[0] := 2

NextPrime[1] := 2

NextPrime[n_Integer] := Block[{res}, res = integerNextPrime[n]; res /; IntegerQ[res]]

NextPrime[r_] /; NumericQ[r] && ! IntegerQ[r] := 
 Block[{res, n}, 
  n = Quiet[Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 
           Max[$MaxExtraPrecision, 1 + Ceiling[Log[10., Abs[N[r]]]]]}, Floor[r]]]; (res = 
     NextPrime[n]; res /; IntegerQ[res]) /; IntegerQ[n]]

NextPrime[n_, k_Integer] /; NumericQ[n] && Positive[k] := 
 Block[{res}, res = Nest[NextPrime, n, k]; res /; IntegerQ[res]]

NextPrime[n_, k_Integer] /; NumericQ[n] && Negative[k] := 
 Block[{res}, res = Nest[PreviousPrime, n, -k]; res /; IntegerQ[res]]

NextPrime[n_?PrimeQ, 0] := n

NextPrime[n_, 0] := NextPrime[n]

NextPrime[n___] := (ArgumentCountQ[NextPrime, Length[{n}], 1, 2]; Null /; False)


integerNextPrime[n_Integer] := 
 Block[{res}, res = n + 1 + Mod[n, 2]; While[! PrimeQ[res], res += 2]; 
  res /; IntegerQ[res]]

integerNextPrime[___] := $Failed


PreviousPrime[n_] := Block[{res}, res = -NextPrime[-n]; res /; IntegerQ[res]]

PreviousPrime[___] := $Failed
```